# MySQL - Transactions and causality

Tags: mysql, locking, transaction, isolation-level

I'm new to MySQL's `LOCK` and `TRANSACTION` and have a question about different isolation levels of a transaction:

Given two transactions executing the same code (auto-commit is false):

```
(1)  get data of row A
(2)  write fetched data increased by 1 to row A
(3)  commit
```

And let's assume that the isolation-level is `REPEATABLE_READ`. This means that in `(2)` the value that gets increased by 1 needs to be the same as fetched in `(1)`. But if the two transactions execute at the same time this might happen if there is no mutual exclusion involved:

*Transaction 1 and 2:*

```
(1) read value of 4
(2) write 5
(3) commit
```

They would both see 4 and then write 5 even though the result should be 6. So do I have to do locking there myself or does MySQL take care of the locking?